# How to remove extra space between div border and text when text is set with em?

Tags: css

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/E8QHb/2/

A simple div with text:

```
<div class="TL">Text</div>
```

And this css:

```
.TL {
    font-size: 2em;   
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

There is no padding or margin at all, yet there is space rendered between the text and the red border. I want the red border to touch the text all the way around **without** using a pixel based height or line-height.

I've tried `line-height:auto`, `line-height:auto`, `height:auto`, `display:inline-block`, and `display:block`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Given that this depends on the font as well as the character glyphs being used, what should happen if the capital T is removed? Should the box shrink its height so it touches the tallest lowercase letter? I don't think CSS allows for that sort of thing.

Comment: The closest you'll probably be able to get with CSS alone would be using a unit-less line-height something like: http://jsfiddle.net/E8QHb/10/

Answer (score 1):

Just use line-height in em?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E8QHb/8/)**

CSS:

```
.TL {
    ...
    line-height: 0.65em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: kind of but that value depends on `font-family`